# How to query months and group them in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which sums up the transactions of a given month over a given period in SQL Server. I want to list the months and transactions in a table but the `DATENAME()` function is only returning one month i.e January in the list. The query is as shown below ..

```sql
SELECT 
    DATENAME(MONTH, DATEPART(MONTH FROM TransactionDate)) AS Month_Name, 
    SUM(ABS(Income)) AS Income 
FROM 
    Transactions 
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(MONTH FROM TransactionDate)
```

Please help ...

Comment: The function datename is able to find the month name from the entire date. You don't need to use datepart here. Try without, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
  datename(mm,TransactionDate) AS Month_Name, 
  SUM(ABS(Income)) AS Income 
FROM Transactions 
GROUP BY 
  datename(mm, TransactionDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select datename(mm, TransactionDate) month_name, sum(income) income
from transactions
group by month_name
```

Remove some unnecessary to tune up the performance.

Comment: This kind of GROUP by usage is not allowed in SQL Server, you need to write GROUP BY datename(mm, TransactionDate). Also removing the ABS compared to the original query when summing the income is not "tuning up performance", but will produce a completely different result whenever negative incomes exist.